# Parsing JSON by Gson

Tags: android, json, gson

I have JSON. Actually I present my POJO class to yours because my JSON like it and I want put JSON to in it.
  I've seen videos from YouTube and Googling but they have parsed all info JSON to their class. Not part of attribute JSON.

```
public class Earthquake {
List<Property> properties;

public List<Property> getProperties() {
    return properties;
}

public void setProperties(List<Property> properties) {
    this.properties = properties;
}
}
```

And:

```
public class Property {

private String mMagnitude;
private String mLocation;
private long mDate;

public Property(String mMagnitude, String mLocation, long mDate) {
    this.mMagnitude = mMagnitude;
    this.mLocation = mLocation;
    this.mDate = mDate;
}

public String getmMagnitude() {
    return mMagnitude;
}

public String getmLocation() {
    return mLocation;
}

public long getmDate() {
    return mDate;
}
}
```

this is [json online api](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2016-01-01&endtime=2016-01-31&minmagnitude=6).in my practice I want put some information that there are in the "features" list and "properties" object into my Earthquake pojo class.as you can see there is a list of Property attribute. I just need "mag", "place", "time" of Property attribute.
 I want parse this JSON by JSON.How can I do it?

I used this way for parsing:

```
    List<Earthquake> earthquakes = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(earthQuakeJSON);
        JSONArray earthquakeArray = baseJsonResponse.optJSONArray("features");

        for (int i = 0; i < earthquakeArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject currentEarthquake = earthquakeArray.optJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject properties = currentEarthquake.optJSONObject("properties");
            String magnitude = properties.getString("mag");
            String location = properties.getString("place");
            long time = properties.getLong("time");
            Earthquake earthquake = new Earthquake(magnitude, location, time);
            earthquakes.add(earthquake);
        }
```

But how can I do by Gson?

Comment: Y don't your try retrofit, it has its own converter & easy to use as well. another benefit will reduce boilerplate code & so much manual effort too. your code would be easy to read.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've even tried using Gson. Please do so before posting your question.

Comment: I do agree with @cricket_007. That's how I started the Json>GSON >Retrofit. Starting from Json and Gson gives quite a mental picture of how the json parsing works.Leaping to Retrofit without using Gson seems to unhealthy.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the json data I believe you are using the EarthQuake and Properties in a wrong way

- You don't need EarthQuake object with getter and setter for list of Properties
- You can just rename the Properties class to Earthquake which would be our actual list to be parsed.

```
public class Property {

    @SerializedName("mag")
    private String mMagnitude;

    @SerializedName("place")
    private String mLocation;

    @SerializedName("time")
    private long mDate;

    public Property(String mMagnitude, String mLocation, long mDate) {
        this.mMagnitude = mMagnitude;
        this.mLocation = mLocation;
        this.mDate = mDate;
    }

    public String getmMagnitude() {
        return mMagnitude;
    }

    public String getmLocation() {
        return mLocation;
    }

    public long getmDate() {
        return mDate;
    }
}
```

Finally to parse the json use this...

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listOfEarthQuake= new TypeToken<List<Earthquake>>() {}.getType();
return gson.fromJson(earthQuakeString,listOfEarthQuake);
```

Comment: The JSON doesn't contain the string "mMagnitude", so you need Gson Property annotations here

Comment: I used your code but how can i pass this gson.fromJson(earthQuakeString,listOfEarthQuake) to the recyclerview adapter? i do this way [link](http://codepad.org/HD7fcTQN) but i got this error:`Method threw  java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.example.sayres.mygsonerthquake.HttpRequest$1.toString()` this is my method of GSON :[link](http://codepad.org/Ua6e17In) . this method return **List<Earthquake>**

Comment: This link might help you to parse the complex json http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/  (set source type json, annotation style GSON)

Comment: @AmitBhandari .it is not complex .it is just an list of 3 attribute. maybe i have to ask another question about this problem.

Comment: @sayreskabir Since you are quiet familiar with json, GSON does the same think but instead of collecting primitive data from jsobObject, GSON would internally handle it and hand us the data at object level. So if you use jsonschema2pojo is would give where your 3 attributes actually lies. The bad part is you would be creating few wrapper pojo which would holds your actual 3 atttibutes under "properties" parent attributes. Or you could check out gson serializer/deserializer for  more insight . But I stick to the first one at current state.

Answer (score 0):

i tried your code but doesnt work :

i made some change if it can help you :

**Earthquake**

```
     import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Earthquake {
    ArrayList<Property> properties= new ArrayList<Property>();

    public Earthquake(long t , long m , String p){
        Property pr = new Property(m ,p, t);
        properties.add(pr);
    }

}
```

**Property**

```
public class Property {

private long mMagnitude;
private String mLocation;
private long mDate;

public Property(long mMagnitude, String mLocation, long mDate) {
    this.mMagnitude = mMagnitude;
    this.mLocation = mLocation;
    this.mDate = mDate;
}


}
```

**Main**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.gson.Gson;


public class MainProp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        List<Earthquake> earthquakes = new ArrayList<Earthquake>();
         List<Earthquake> fromjson = new ArrayList<Earthquake>();


            JSONParser jsp = new JSONParser();
            String url ="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2016-01-01&endtime=2016-01-31&minmagnitude=6";
                JSONObject obj = jsp.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET");


            JSONArray earthquakeArray = obj.getJSONArray("features");//baseJsonResponse.optJSONArray("features");

            for (int i = 0; i < earthquakeArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentEarthquake = earthquakeArray.optJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject properties = currentEarthquake.optJSONObject("properties");
                Iterator<?> keys = properties.keys();

                long time =0;
                String location ="";
                long magnitude =0;
                Earthquake earthquake  = null;
                   while( keys.hasNext() ) {
                       String key = (String)keys.next();
                          if("time".equals(key))
                              time = properties.getLong("time");
                              if("place".equals(key))
                                   location = properties.getString("place");
                                  if("mag".equals(key)) 
                                       magnitude = properties.getLong("mag");

                                  if(!"".equals(location) && time !=0 && magnitude != 0){
                                      earthquake = new Earthquake(time,magnitude,location);
                                      earthquakes.add(earthquake);
                                  }
                          }

                   Gson gson = new Gson();
                      String json = gson.toJson(earthquake);
                      System.out.println(json);

                      Earthquake fromjsonItem =  gson.fromJson(json, Earthquake.class);

                       fromjson.add(fromjsonItem);


            }


        }

}
```

**Parser** DefaultHttpClient is now deprecated :(

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {
    }
    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method) {
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);  
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jObj; 
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]